# Python Flask WTForms how to load 2nd dropdown using jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask, flask-wtforms

if we have two dropdowns in WTForm how to load second drop down with choices based on choice selected from first dropdown list using jquery ajax call

Initially the second dropdown choices defined in WTForm as empty list, when loaded second dropdown using ajax call and form submitted the form showing with error as Not a valid choice for second dropdown

```
class LegacyUserInfoForm(Form):
    tpinfoList = []
    for tpinfo in TpInfo.query.all():
        tpinfoList.append((tpinfo.id,tpinfo.name))
    sftpHostInfoList = []
    tpInfo = SelectField('Trading Partner',coerce=int,choices=tpinfoList)
    sftpHostInfo = SelectField('Sftp Host',coerce=int,choices=sftpHostInfoList)
    user = TextField('User Name',validators=[Required()])
    passwd = PasswordField('Password', validators=[Required()])
    inbpath = TextAreaField('Inbound Path',validators=[Required(),Length(min=10, max=255)])
    obdpath = TextAreaField('Outbound Path', validators=[Length(min=10, max=255)]) 
    filename = TextAreaField('File Name',validators=[Required(),Length(min=10, max=255)])
    submit = SubmitField('Add Legacy User Info')


@app.route('/legacyuserinfo',methods=['GET','POST'])
def legacyUserInfoPage():
    form = LegacyUserInfoForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        tpInfo = TpInfo.query.filter_by(id=form.tpInfo.data).first()
        sftpHostInfo = SftpHostInfo.query.filter_by(id=form.sftpHostInfo.data).first()
        legacyUserInfo = LegacyUserInfo(form.user.data,form.passwd.data,form.inbpath.data,form.obdpath.data,form.filename.data,tpInfo,sftpHostInfo)
        db.session.add(legacyUserInfo)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/home')



    return render_template('legacyuserinfo.html',form=form)

@app.route('/load_sftphostslist/<tpInfoId>')
def loadSftpHostsList(tpInfoId):
    selectedTpInfo = TpInfo.query.filter_by(id=tpInfoId).first()
    #sftpHostsInfoList = []
    #for sftphost in SftpHostInfo.query.filter_by(tpInfo=selectedTpInfo):
        #sftpHostsInfoList.append((sftphost.id,sftphost.host))   
    return render_template('load_sftphostslist.html',list=SftpHostInfo.query.filter_by(tpInfo=selectedTpInfo))
```

## Template

```
{% extends "master-template.html"%}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% block title %}Welcome To Web Interface of TPInfo Application{% endblock %}
{% block navbar %}
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li ><a href="/tpinfo">TP Info</a></li>
    <li ><a href="/tpkeyinfo">TP Key Info</a></li>
    <li ><a href="/sftphostinfo">SFTP Host Info</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="/legacyuserinfo">Legacy User Info</a></li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
{% block contents %}
<h1>New Trading Partner Legacy User Info</h1>
<hr/>
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
{%endblock%}
{%block load_script%}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#tpInfo").change(function() {
    tpInfoId = $("#tpInfo").val()
    $.ajax({
           type : "GET",
           url : '/load_sftphostslist/'+tpInfoId
       }).done(function(html){
        $("#sftpHostInfo").replaceWith(html)
       });
});
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

## Screen Shot

[image: Screenshot of Form with issue]

Comment: I think you'd be better off adding ALL of the choices in  for your `SFTP host`, and then removing the unneeded ones via JavaScript, depending upon the selected value in `Trading Partner`.

Comment: @rnevius, what if the user selected again another trading partner at the same time?